# How to change pgAdmin 4 to display rows retrieved and runtime?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I've just switched from pgAdmin III to pgAdmin 4, and while overall it seems a lot slicker in terms of UI and presentation, I'm missing a few things from the previous version. In particular, I would show the execution time and number of rows retrieved at the bottom right on the results for selections. In 4, I see a small green popup that contains that information, but disappears after a few seconds. I've found the setting in File->Preferences->SQL Editor->Display called "Query info notifier timeout" that lets me keep the popup there indefinitely until clicked. I also don't see any kind of ongoing runtime display while a query is running. Is there any way to display any of this information more permanently?

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of a shame that there is no good solution to this. I found that adding `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to the beginning of my query will display results. Some documentation can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/using-explain.html).

Example:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
select * from schema.my_table limit 1000
```

Yields:

```
"Limit  (cost=0.00..168.48 rows=1000 width=2644) (actual time=0.048..5.214 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"Append  (cost=0.00..13935338.46 rows=82710326 width=2644) (actual time=0.045..4.880 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"Seq Scan on event_analysis_vw  (cost=0.00..459263.46 rows=3764446 width=3186) (actual time=0.040..4.579 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"Seq Scan on dva_event_analysis_field  (cost=0.00..6640119.59 rows=43856549 width=2623) (never executed)"
"Filter: (is_deleted IS NULL)"
"Seq Scan on dva_event_analysis_field_archived  (cost=0.00..6046496.61 rows=35089331 width=2612) (never executed)"
"Filter: (is_deleted IS NULL)"
"Total runtime: 5.977 ms"
```